# Is it safe to use PBEWithMD5AndDES?

Tags: encryption

I'm encrypting some of my (not so much important) files with `PBEWithMD5AndDES`. Is it a strong method or it can be de-crypt easily without knowing my selected `password`?

I'm new to crypto, thanks in advance.

Comment: If this is really DES and not 3DES then it's very weak.

Comment: It can be decrypt in a few hours with brute force?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it can be decrypted easily because it will use DES (CBC) mode of operation. DES only has an effective key size of 56 bits. So the key and the can be brute forced regardless of the (PBKDF1) key derivation.

MD5, while considered broken by itself, is less of an issue when it is used within PBKDF1 - as long as the password contains enough entropy of course.

If possible you should upgrade to Password Based Encryption (PBE) using PBKDF2 and AES. Beware that PBE usually uses CBC mode encryption, so it is not suitable for transport protocols.

Comment: Thanks so much for information, I'll try to upgrade PBE using AES.

Comment: @D.W if you are going to change the algorithm, I would strongly suggest also changing the hash function to at least SHA-1

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, Lets say I encrypted a `.xml` file using `PBEWithMD5AndDES` using `1^$>£¾$½#>£$#<>!!` password. Will it be easily cracked, in a few minutes? I'm using it in my android application.

Comment: No, the current record seems to be around one day, and that with specialized hardware. Ciphers with very low key sizes can therefore be used for realtime protocols. I would not be surprised if the NSA can crack DES in minutes.  But do not know any more than the Wikipedia page on DES.